# How to read file with cyrillic path

Tags: java, character-encoding, filenotfoundexception

Actually I have next code:

```
String f = LauncherFrame.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath(); // path to launcher
java.lang.System.out.println(f);

String launcherHash = "";

try{
  MessageDigest md5  = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
  launcherHash = calculateHash(md5, f);
}catch (Exception e) {
  java.lang.System.out.println(e){
  return;
}
```

**calculateHash** function:

```
public static String calculateHash(MessageDigest algorithm,String fileName) throws Exception{
      FileInputStream    fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
      DigestInputStream  dis = new DigestInputStream(bis, algorithm);

      while (dis.read() != -1);
            byte[] hash = algorithm.digest();

      return byteArray2Hex(hash);
}
```

It's work good on unix/windows when my .jar file haven't cyrillic characters in path. But when it have, I getting next exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
C:\Users\%d0%90%d1%80%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80\Documents\NetBeansProjects\artcraft-client\build\classes (Can't find file)
```

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from memory so the syntax may be a bit off, but the best is probably to use the built in URL support for opening streams directly from an URL;

```
URL url = LauncherFrame.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

then pass the URL to `calculateHash` instead of the filename and use [URL's openStream method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream()) to get a stream with the content;

```
InputStream is = url.openStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
...
```